# Sprite sheet animations using pyganim, Why does my sprite not show?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So if anyone has used pyganim to show sprite sheet animations and could tell me why my code is not showing the animation, I would thank you loads. ive tried moving coordinates and changing fill color. nothing is working and I'm not receiving any errors so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
  import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    import time
    import random
    import pyganim
    import sys
    import os


    rects = [(0, 154, 94, 77),
             (94, 154, 94, 77),
             (188, 154, 94, 77),
             (282, 154, 94, 77),
             (376, 154, 94, 77),
             (470, 154, 94, 77),
             (564, 154, 94, 77),
             (658, 154, 94, 77),]
    file_name = ('explosion1.png')
    images = pyganim.getImagesFromSpriteSheet(file_name, rects = rects)
    frames = list (zip(images, [100] * len(images)))
    animObj = pyganim.PygAnimation(frames)
    animObj.play()
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    pygame.init()
    display_width = 800
    display_height = 600
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('sprite animations')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    def game_loop():
        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        gameExit = False
        while not gameExit:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameExit = True
            animObj.blit(gameDisplay,(100, 50))

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(15)

    game_loop()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: Did you call pygame.display.flip()?

Comment: ok so I changed the sprite sheet and its still pretty messed up because the widths and heights etc are not the same between the two sheets but this now makes me wonder why my first one is not working or showing at all but, the new one is.

Comment: called pygame.display.update(), which correct me if I'm wrong, are the same thing.

Comment: they are not check the doc

Comment: tried but no avail. I'm thinking it has to do with the sprite sheet I'm using but thanks for the input

Comment: Alright new question if you could possibly help, the sprite was the issue, not sure exactly what was wrong with it but I found a new one and it works. but now the problem is the previous images from the sprite are left on the screen as the animation happens, any possible solution on the code? @MosheRabaev

Comment: set the screen back to white when done one frame

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do that, but I did fix it, I feel stupid as I was searching my code for like an hour trying to fix why the sprite stayed after it was drawn, and I finally figured out it was because my gameDisplay.fill(black) was outside of the loop. thanks though @MosheRabaev

Answer (score 1):

Sprite was bad, had to change the sheet, and my gameDisplay.fill(..) was outside of the while loop!